# Webform emails direct

Tags: webform-civicrm

I've created a question on my webforms that require an answer of 'yes' or 'no' 
 I can see there's an instruction of

'The selected component 'xxxxx' has multiple options. You may enter an e-mail address for each choice. When that choice is selected, an e-mail will be sent to the corresponding address. If a field is left blank, no e-mail will be sent for that option'

Is it possible to have one member of staff receive the result of the form if the answer is no, and another person if the answer is yes?

Comment: I think this is technically not a CiviCRM question, since this is a Webform feature and isn't impacted by the use of Webform-CiviCRM.  Maybe better for drupal.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the webform configuration page:

1. Add your Yes/No component
2. Click the Emails button
3. In the E-mail To column select Component Value and choose your Yes/No component
4. Click Add
5. In the Component E-mail options, enter the email addresses to receive mail for Yes and for No.
6. Configure the rest of the email settings as you want

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Aidan.  I've done this, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.  I imagine there is a problem with the mail function...

Comment: Ah yes, you'll need basic mail to work first.  Has that been setup for your Drupal site?

Comment: I thought that it had, as it definitely used to work!  But now I'm not so sure!  Are you able to advise how I can check?